# java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.NUMBER cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CHAR

Tags: java

In the DB have one collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TY_Test as object
(
ID  NUMBER,
ACCOUNT  NUMBER,
PRIORITY CHAR(20), 
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TY_Test_Instance as table of TY_Test
```

And TY_Test_Instance is passed to one procedure.

Below is Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    String[] objs = new String[3];
    objs[0] = new String("863");
    objs[1] = new String("1");
    objs[2] = new String("3");
    Connection conn = DBHelper.getInstance().conn;
    StructDescriptor sDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("TY_Test", conn);
    list.add(new STRUCT(sDescriptor, conn, objs));
    Object[] obj_array = list.toArray();
    ArrayDescriptor aDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TY_Test_Instance", conn);
    ARRAY array = new ARRAY(aDescriptor, conn, obj_array);
    CallableStatement cstm = conn.prepareCall("{call PR_TEST(?,?)}");
    cstm.setInt(1, 123);
    cstm.setArray(2, array);
    cstm.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
    cstm.execute();
    if (cstm.getInt(1) != 0) {
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

when execute the script, it pop ups `java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.NUMBER cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CHAR in the code of cstm.setArray(2, array);`

I have spent much time but have not got any solution. Please help on it.

Comment: Add code of `PR_TEST` procedure here please.

Comment: TY_TEST is defined as NUMBER. NUMBER, CHAR(20), but objs contains Strings. Try to pass Integer, Integer, String instead.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment. The problem is that i have no privilege to change the variable type. Have to use it as char. Any idea how to handle it?

Comment: I wrote about your java part: objs[0] = new Integer(863); etc

Comment: objs[0] = new Integer(863), it is fine. For objs[2] = new String("3"), it is treated as number by the oracle. Since the variable defined in collection is char, when the code cast it to char, error messages pop up.

Comment: sorry, it does not make sense. I would try to locate the issue by reducing complexity, e.g. removing irrelevant / working parts. Try to create new Oracle TYPE with just PRIORITY CHAR(20) column and updating the rest of SQL/Java code. Would it run or fail again? If it fails, create more simple PL/SQL procedure / share it.